# How do I add blank element to index[0] of an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `User` and `Role` model.

In roles table I have.

```
ID      name
1       admin
2       normal_user
3       guest
```

In users table I have `role_id`.

I am using enum to my User and I tried this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum role_id: (Role.all).map {|k,v| k[:name]}
end
```

The problem of this is 0 => admin, 1 => normal_user, 2 => guest, instead of the ID. How am I going to solve this? I am thinking to add blank element to index[0].

something like this.

`enum role_id: ["", :admin, :normal_user, :guest]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role_id: ([''] + Role.all.map(&:name))
end
```

Comment: Looks like I didnot refresh the page; @Zahid has given similar answer; however there is little difference

Comment: Thanks , I used your answer ^_^

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem.

```
enum role_id: [''] + Role.all.map {|k,v| k[:name]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update this below part as:

```
enum_role_id:   (Role.all).map {|k,v| k[:name]}.insert(0,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for enum, you can give enum a Hash instead of an array, so I think you could easily build up a Hash this way:

```
enum role_id: (Role.all).each_with_object({}) do |row, hash| 
  hash[row[:name]] = row[:id] 
end
```

That way you wouldn't need to add an empty row to the table, and each name maps to the correct id.

Comment: This is nice also. Thanks for this +1 . But I used @illusionist's answer and that's what I need for now.